# Rails - How do you test ActionMailer sent a specific email in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, actionmailer

Currently in my tests I do something like this to test if an email is queued to be sent

```
assert_difference('ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size', 1) do       
  get :create_from_spreedly, {:user_id => @logged_in_user.id}
end
```

but if i a controller action can send two different emails i.e. one to the user if sign up goes fine or a notification to admin if something went wrong - how can i test which one actually got sent. The code above would pass regardless.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When using the ActionMailer during tests, all mails are put in a big array called `deliveries`. What you basically are doing (and is sufficient mostly) is checking if emails are present in the array.
But if you want to specifically check for a certain email, you have to know what is actually stored in the array. Luckily the emails themselves are stored, thus you are able to iterate through the array and check each email.

See [ActionMailer::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) to see what configuration methods are available, which you can use to determine what emails are present in the array. Some of the most suitable methods for your case probably are

- `recipients`: Takes one or more email addresses. These addresses are where your email will be delivered to. Sets the To: header.
- `subject`: The subject of your email. Sets the Subject: header.

Answer (score 83):

As of rails 3 ActionMailer::Base.deliveries is an array of Mail::Message's.  From the [mail documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail):

```
#  mail['from'] = 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
#  mail[:to]    = 'you@test.lindsaar.net'
#  mail.subject 'This is a test email'
#  mail.body    = 'This is a body'
# 
#  mail.to_s #=> "From: mikel@test.lindsaar.net\r\nTo: you@...
```

From that it should be easy to test your mail's in an integration

```
mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last

assert_equal 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net', mail['from'].to_s

assert_equal 'you@test.lindsaar.net', mail['to'].to_s
```

Comment: You can also use: "assert ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size >= 1 (or == 2)" to check multiple mails are sent.
and to verify multiple subjects, and emails use "ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last(2)"

Answer (score 21):

Using current Rspec syntax, I ended up using the following:

```
last_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
expect(last_email.to).to eq ['test@example.com']
expect(last_email.subject).to have_content 'Welcome'
```

The context of my test was a feature spec where I wanted to make sure a welcome email was sent to a user after signing up.

Answer (score 13):

As of 2020 (Rails 6 era, probably introduced earlier) you can do the following:
(using a SystemTest example) TL;DR: use `assert_emails` from `ActionMailer::TestHelper` and `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last` to access the mail itself.

```rb
require "application_system_test_case"
require 'test_helper'
require 'action_mailer/test_helper'

class ContactTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  include ActionMailer::TestHelper

  test "Send mail via contact form on landing page" do
    visit root_url

    fill_in "Message", with: 'message text'

    # Asserting a mail is sent
    assert_emails 1 do
      click_on "Send"
    end

    # Asserting stuff within that mail
    last_email  = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last

    assert_equal ['whatever'], last_email.reply_to
    assert_equal "contact", last_email.subject
    assert_match /Mail from someone/, last_email.body.to_s
  end
end
```

Official doc:

- [ActionMailer Guide/Testing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-testing)
- [Testing Guide/ActionMailer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers)

**Note**
Instead of manually checking the content of the mail as in the system test above, you can also test whether a specific mailer action was used, like this:

```rb
assert_enqueued_email_with ContactMailer, :welcome, args: ["Hello", "Goodbye"]
```

And some other handy assertion, see https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.2/classes/ActionMailer/TestHelper.html#method-i-assert_emails .

Answer (score 3):

The test framework [shoulda](http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) has an excellent helper which lets you assert certain conditions about an email that was sent. Yes, you could do it yourself with ActionMailer.deliveries, but shoulda makes it all one neat little block

Comment: that's the `have_sent_email` matcher http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/shoulda/2.11.3/Shoulda/ActionMailer/Matchers (e.g.  `it { should have_sent_email.with_subject(/spam/).from('do-not-reply@example.com').with_body(/spam/).to('myself@me.com') }`

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but it may help others:

You could use [Email-spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec), a collection of Rspec/Minitest matchers and Cucumber steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best way I've found to do it.

1) Include the [action mailer callbacks](http://github.com/AnthonyCaliendo/action_mailer_callbacks) plugin like this:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/AnthonyCaliendo/action_mailer_callbacks.git
```

I don't really use the plugin's main features, but it does provide the nice functionality of being able to figure out which method was used to send an email.

2) Now you can put some methods in your test_helper.rb like this:

```
  def assert_sent(method_name)
    assert sent_num_times(method_name) > 0
  end

  def assert_not_sent(method_name)
    assert sent_num_times(method_name) == 0
  end

  def assert_sent_once(method_name)
    assert sent_num_times(method_name) == 1
  end

  def sent_num_times(method_name)
    count = 0
    @emails.each do |email|
      count += 1 if method_name == email.instance_variable_get("@method_name")
    end
    count
  end
```

3) Now you can write sweet tests like this:

```
require 'test_helper'
class MailingTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @emails = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries
    @emails.clear
  end

  test "should send a mailing" do
    assert_difference "Mailing.count", 1 do
      feeds(:feed1).generate_mailing
    end

    assert_sent_once "broadcast"
    assert_not_sent "failed_mailing"
  end
end
```

Here "broadcast" and "mailing_failed" are the names of the methods in my ActionMailer::Base class.  These are the ones you normally use by calling `Mailer.deliver_broadcast(some_data)` or `Mailer.deliver_failed_mailing(some_data)` etc.  That's it!