# How do I test that an email has been sent and delivered with rspec2 in a controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, rspec-rails

I test my views in controller specs. Is this possible with email too?
If so can someone show me an example?

I'm currently working on integration tests:
I've taking some code from testing for signup and converting it so I can test my reset password but stuck on the email part.

```
describe "Reset Password" do

    describe "success" do

    it "should send the user reset password instructions" do

      lambda do
        visit reset_password_path
        fill_in "password_reset[email]",            :with => "mememe@gmail.com"      
       # click_button "password_reset_submit"
       # response.should render_template :js => "window.location = '#{temp_success_path}'"
     #  end.should change(User, :count)

    end
  end
end
end
```

I've set up emails for signup and reset password. On successfuly signup user is sent an email to welcome them to the website. On password reset user is sent an email with password reset instructons.

Part of passwords controller:

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:password_reset][:email])
    @user.generate_and_store_password_reset_token && UserMailer.password_reset(@user).deliver if @user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions."
  end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])     
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save 
        UserMailer.join_confirmation(@user).deliver
        format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{temp_success_path}'" }

      else

        format.html { render :new }  
        format.js   { render :form_errors }
      end
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: You'll find good explanations to test emails in [this Railscast](https://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - How do you test ActionMailer sent a specific email in tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063438/rails-how-do-you-test-actionmailer-sent-a-specific-email-in-tests)