# How to write tests for email views in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, testing, capybara

In ActiveAdmin I have setup a small form for sending bulk emails to users. In the form I have the option to parse text using html or markdown. I have two different views and depending on the content type attribute of the email, one of the two is rendered. I pass the `@content` of the email to the views and in the one I call `simple_format @content` and in the other - a helper method `markdown @content`. So the question is - how do I test the email views. Everywhere I see ways to preview emails in the browser, but I want to have some written tests, which I can run along with my full test suit. So far, the only idea I have come up with is to use Capybara and something like:

```
visit '/mail_view'
expect(find 'a.reset_password').to contain reset_password_path(user)
```

Is this the way to go or is there another standard?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the contents of ActionMailer::Base.deliveries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - How do you test ActionMailer sent a specific email in tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063438/rails-how-do-you-test-actionmailer-sent-a-specific-email-in-tests)