# How to test if mail is sent based of created object field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to Rspec, i am trying to write a test for a simple feature.

A user creates a contract, if the contract the is created and has a specific value on its property then i send an email to notify the teacher.
 How do i write the condition in the test?

I am using letter_opener and ActionMailer.

```rb
describe "When a user creates a apprentice contract" do
 let(:admin) { users(:admin) }
 before { signin admin }

  it "should send an email to the teacher" do
    contract = create(:contract)
    contract.education_type.must_equal("company_apprentice")  
  end
end
```

when `contract.education_type.must_equal("school_apprentice")` is true  i want to test if it sends an email.

How do i write that in this test?

Answer (score 1):

```
it 'should send an email to the teacher' do
  expect { create(:contract, education_type: 'company_apprentice' }
    .to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }
    .by(1)
end
```

you also need this set:

```
# config/environments/test.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

Comment: Im getting an error ```NoMethodError: undefined method `change' ```

Comment: im using the ```minitest-spec-rails```

Comment: You do something like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17223583/5841310 or at least check if `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size` is equal to 1.

Comment: minitest-spec-rails is not the same thing at all as rspec. minitest is a completely different test framework. minitest-spec lets you write "BDD" style tests for minitest.

Comment: If you are using minitest and rails you can use [`assert_changes` or `assert_difference`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.6/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html) to replicate `expect {}.to change` from RSpec. If you want to learn BDD style testing I would go with RSpec though as its a tight well tested and well documented kit whereas doing BDD with minitest is like a plastic bag filled with odd parts.